# What is the latest version of Gradle that Team City 7 supports?

Tags: gradle, teamcity

What is the latest version of `Gradle` supported by `TeamCity 7` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the gradle wrapper, you should be able to use the latest 2.8 gradle release with Teamcity 7

Comment: Yes but what if not using gradle wrapper?